# How do I view the contents of my "default" type Cloud SQL database in AppMaker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I created a new [AppMaker](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/) app and selected the "default" (as opposed to "custom") [Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql) database backend.

While I'm prototyping my app, I'd like to be able to inspect the contents of my database periodically as an admin to debug issues. With a custom Cloud SQL database this is easy because you can acess a custom Cloud SQL database from the cloud console, but I don't see how to manually query a default Cloud SQL database.

I know that I can export my database to a Google Sheet, but that's inconvenient to do frequently.

How do I inspect the contents of my AppMaker default Cloud SQL database for debugging (eg. via a SQL command line, UI tool, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be the same as with the **custom** one. The documentation explains:

> A G Suite administrator can set up a Google Cloud SQL instance that is shared among App Maker apps in an organization. When this is enabled, a new database is automatically created for your app when you add at least one Cloud SQL data model. Choose this option if your app needs a database that is easy to use and requires no set up.

This means that you had set up correctly the instance information in the G Suite Admin console:

[image]

So to connect to your SQL instance, you just need to follow the [instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/external-connection-methods?hl=en_US&_ga=2.117353286.-1508369444.1539541278). Then simply use the instance connection name where required. You will also need the database name and you can get that from the appsettings or deployment settings in appmaker.

For the preview mode it will be in the app settings. For any deployed version, it will be in the deployment settings:

[image]

Comment: Hm, I still can't seem to get this working for a default db created inside appmaker

Comment: Then edit your question and be more detailed with each step and method you are utilizing to do the connection. With more info, perhaps we should be able to help.